# Excel VBA splitting up rows

Tags: excel, vba

If in a cell of a table of data contains a value x > 1, I would like to copy and paste the row containing that cell "x" number of times. The rows would paste with x = 1 in the next available blank row.

---

`TREVDAN    2 
 CENTRAL    3 
 GAL FAB    1`

From this.

---

`TREVDAN    1 
 TREVDAN    1 
 CENTRAL    1 
 CENTRAL    1
 CENTRAL    1
 GAL FAB    1`

To looking something like this.

Comment: Welcome to SO! [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do your rows contain just values?  Or might there also be formulas in some of the cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you.

```
Sub SpecialCopy()
    'Assuming A and B columns source columns
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    Dim j As Long: j = 1
    For i = 1 To Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        k = 1
        Do While k <= Range("B" & i).Value
            'Assuming C and D are destination columns
            Range("C" & j).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
            Range("D" & j).Value = 1
            j = j + 1
            k = k + 1
        Loop
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What if I were to want to expand the number of columns to be more than just 2?

Answer (score 0):

Building off of the answer provided by @Jeanno, you can use the following if you want to paste the results directly over the top of the original table:

```
Sub SpecialCopy()

'Assuming A and B columns source columns
Dim i As Long, k As Long
Dim j As Long: j = 1
Dim ArrayLength As Long: ArrayLength = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet.Range("B:B"))
ReDim MyArray(1 To ArrayLength) As String

For i = 1 To Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    k = 1
    Do While k <= Range("B" & i).Value
        MyArray(j) = Range("A" & i).Value
        j = j + 1
        k = k + 1
    Loop
Next i

For Each MyCell In Range("a1:a" & ArrayLength)
MyCell.Value = MyArray(MyCell.Row())
MyCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 1
Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Comment: How could i modify this code to work for the quantity value being in the 3rd  column and the 1st, 2nd, and 4th columns are other data?

Comment: The line `Do While k <= Range("B" & i).Value)` is where you specify the column letter corresponding to whichever column has your numbers in it, you will also need to update the `ArrayLength` variable to look at the same column if switching it from Col B to something else. If you need to store additional values then you can create more arrays just like the first one - `ReDim MyArray2(1 To ArrayLength) As String`, copy values into this array with `MyArray2(j) = Range("B" & i).Value`, then paste those values in the results with an offset - `MyCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = MyArray2(MyCell.Row())`